# Why do I need to enter the Stack Exchange password so many times?

Tags: support, login, openid, association, password

After, for example, a cookie reset I need to log in again.

Why do I need to enter the password N times for N Stack Exchange sites? Isn't the account consolidated?

Sometimes I can wait for some time and refresh the page and it says at a top something like "Oh, it's you. Click here for the login.", but not in this case.

Comment: ... What do you mean?

Comment: For example, I go to stackexchange.com. See that it's not logged it. I log in (entering password for StackExchange's OpenID). Then I go to superuser.com. Expected: logged in, Actual: need to enter the same password again.

Comment: This is dependent on your OpenID provider.  If the provider remembers your credentials, you don't need to do that.

Comment: do you block Javascript in some way? Afaik you need to have `stackauth.com` whitelisted for the autologin to work.

Comment: `stackauth.com` is in allow list.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood you, as your question isn't 100% clear...

> After, for example, cookie reset I need to log in again.

This is default behavior for all websites which use a cookie based authentication system. If the session is reset somehow, including deleting cookies, then you are logged out.

> Why do I need to enter the password N times for N Stack Exchange sites? Isn't the account consolidated?

You shouldn't need to. 
If you are logged in to one Stack Exchange site and visit another which you have already associated your account with, then you should either:

1. Be auto logged in when you visit, and just click the refresh in the
   top banner
2. Sometimes happens when you need to manually click "login", but then
   you should only need to click the login method after that and the
   site will get your cookie from the other site you are logged in from

Although this does depend on your login method. Can you give more information?

> Sometimes I can wait for some time and refresh the page and it says at
>   a top something like "Oh, it's you. Click here for the login.", but
>   not in this case

Did you clear cookies? Which would log you out of all sites.

Can you describe the actual issue in a little more detail?

Comment: I restored the browser profile from a backup. The "1. Be auto logged in .. 2. ... only need to click 'log in' ..." does not hold.

Comment: One more idea: maybe the privacy-related browser extensions interferes with this cookie exchange process?